# Python sqlite3 misinterpreting parameter

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to put a column name into a SQL query thusly

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('path/to/my/database.sqlite')
cur = db.cursor()

def get_val(field):
    return cur.execute('''
        SELECT x, y, :field FROM literal_table
        WHERE 
            :valid_field_name > 0 AND
            (some other conditions)
        GROUP BY x, y''',
        {'field': field}).fetchall()

get_val('valid_field_name')
```

but when I execute the code, instead of grabbing the value from the column, python is returning

```
[(x1, y1, u'valid_field_name'), (x2, y3, u'valid_field_name'), ...]
```

I know that you can't encode table names, but there are examples in the docs of column names being parametrized.  I've hacked together a solution with string formatting (the code's for private data processing, so SQL injection isn't a problem) but I need to understand what's going on!

I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: I don't see the problem, the code is doing what is supposed to do. Be aware that you are returning the result of `cur.execute` sql query, and that is a tuple.

Comment: What examples in the docs?

Comment: It would appear I read the docs too quickly; `select ?` is present, but not `select ? from ...`.

Comment: Also, thanks @ManuelGutierrez.  I've added .fetchall() and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite replaces parameters with the supplied values.
In your case, this would be the same as:

```sql
SELECT x, y, 'valid_field_name' FROM literal_table
WHERE 'valid_field_name' > 0 AND (some other conditions)
GROUP BY x, y
```

In other words, strings are strings; it is not possible to have parameters as column names.